# Find String Array Difference in Java

Tags: java, arrays, set-difference

I created two array variables: s1 and s2
s1 contains {ram,raju,seetha}
s2 contains {ram}

I want to subtract the two arrays as sets, in order to get the following result:

raju
 seetha

How can I do this?

Comment: What if `s1 = {"a", "b"}` and `s2 = {"c", "d"}`, what would your difference array be? `{"a", "b"}` or `{"a", "b", "c", "d"}`?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207673/missing-elements-from-two-arrays-in-java

Answer (score 7):

If the elements in your array are unique, you could create a [java.util.Set](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) and do a [removeAl(...)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29). If they're not unique, go for a [java.util.List](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) instead.

Answer (score 4):

You could get the difference by looping through the items:

```
String[] s1 = {"ram", "raju", "seetha"};
String[] s2 = {"ram"};
List<String> s1List = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(s1));
for (String s : s2) {
  if (s1List.contains(s)) {
    s1List.remove(s);
  }
  else {
    s1List.add(s);
  }
}
```

`s1List` contains the different between the two arrays.

Comment: Added this just for the sake of providing an implementation. If I had this problem myself I would go with Bart K.'s solution.

Comment: You cannot modify a list, which is created with `Arrays.asList(...)`.

Comment: @jarnbjo True, changed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To implement this yourself (e.g. if this is homework and you did not learn about the Java collections API yet) you could approach it like this: for every element in the first array, add the element to the result, if it is not contained in the other array. The real-world solution would be to use sets, [as described by Bart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220752/find-string-array-difference-in-java/2220776#2220776).

Answer (score 0):

```
public ArrayList getUnique( ArrayList original, ArrayList subset ){
        ArrayList u = new ArrayList();
        Collection<ArrayList> o = original;
        Collection<ArrayList> s = subset;

        o.removeAll(s);
        u.addAll(o);

        return u;
}
```

You can reduce a few lines from above code but I have kept it for clarity.